# Can GNU Radio modulate and demodulate a text file?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm new to sdr, dsp, and GNU Radio. My goal is to create an FSK demodulator for a project at work ([described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898574/fsk-demodulation-with-gnu-radio)), but since I haven't been making progress, I'm trying to teach myself some of the basics.

For practice, I'm trying to set up a GNU Radio flowchart that reads a text file, modulates it, then demodulates it, returning the same text as output.

**Basic question:** is it possible to read a text file, mod/demod, then return plain, readable text using GNU Radio? I'm trying to send and receive something simple, like "Test, one two three."

**Next question:** if the above is possible, where am I going wrong in the following flowchart (the output file has size (~200 kb), but appears blank)?

[image: Modulate and demodulate a text file with GNU Radio]
Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

The file sink acts as a giant buffer for the data type that you choose.
To output a readable text, I chose to use a byte file sink and convert the binary data to ASCII/UTF-8 values ie add 48 to the stream.

Comment: Adding an "Add Const" block with value 48 did make the output have output. Unfortunately still not the correct values. If I send value "1" in as either a file source or vector source all that's returned is "000." Does that mean anything to you? Do you have any references for how adding 48 to binary values turn them into ASCII?