# MPT1327 FSK Clock and data recovery

Tags: signal-processing, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have to reverse engineer mobile radio terminal over air polling responses to recover location data. I can recover the bit-stream using gnu radio [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898574/fsk-demodulation-with-gnu-radio)
but cannot get the clock recovery module to work. Data is 1200 Baud, CRC16 so can move onto decoding once I can sink data to a file.

[image: My GNU radio demod]

[image: Demod output]

Comment: I'd suggest embedding those two images to your question rather than having links to other websites. It will improve your question a lot.

Comment: I'm don't  have privileges to embed  images.